# UserDefaults always returns nil

Tags: swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, codable

I have this struct

```
//GLOBAL STRUCT USER
struct User: Codable{
    var info: UserInfo?
}
//MARK:-USER INFO
struct UserInfo: Codable{
    var companyName: String?
    var companyAddress: String?
    var companyCity: String?
    var companyCap: String?
    var companyTelephone: String?
    var companyFax: String?
    var companyMobile: String?
    var companyWeb: String?
    var companyEmail: String?
    var companyVat: String?
    var companySDI: String?
    var companyPEC: String?
    var companyLogo: Data?
    
}
```

I save and read datas with this:

```
struct LocalData{
    static var userDatas: User {
            get {
                guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: #function) else {
                    return User(info: UserInfo(companyName: "", companyAddress: "", companyCity: "", companyCap: "", companyTelephone: "", companyFax: "", companyMobile: "", companyWeb: "", companyEmail: "", companyVat: "", companySDI: "", companyPEC: "", companyLogo: Data()))
                    
                }
                do {
                    let datas = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                    return datas
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                return User(info: UserInfo(companyName: "", companyAddress: "", companyCity: "", companyCap: "", companyTelephone: "", companyFax: "", companyMobile: "", companyWeb: "", companyEmail: "", companyVat: "", companySDI: "", companyPEC: "", companyLogo: Data()))
            }
            set{
                guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) else { return }
                UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: #function)
            }
        }

}
```

If I store any datas, for example:

```
LocalData.userDatas.info?.companyAddress = "TEST"
```

when I restart app (not from background but I close and reopen), if I put a break inside "viewWillAppear" and I write into console

```
po LocalData.userDatas
```

all datas inside LocalData.userDatas are nil

Comment: Could you please provide more details? There are some things that don't make much sense... `LocalData.userDatas.companyAddress = "TEST" ` shouldn't be `LocalData.userDatas.info.companyAddress = "TEST"` ? and what is `userGroup`? This is not clear from the code snipped you shared here.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I have edit my question